# How to Stop Sitecatalyst Visit Tracking Increment for particular web App

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I have a page “Googlesapp_welcome”  is showing up in the my home page report suite and accounting for ~10000 visits per month.  I know this is necessary to enable the tracking of the registration process.  But what is the best way to remove it from reporting?  Is it to change the sitecatalyst code on this page to not increment a visit?  Is it just to filter it out of our reporting.
(But I have to keep in mind with all reporting in the future prospective)

Comment: can you explain why it is both necessary for enabling tracking of the registration process, AND something you don't want to see in your reports? Those two things are usually mutually exclusive...

Comment: reason I ask is because there multiple ways to keep it from showing up, but "keep it from showing up" is kind of a broad term and has implications on other things..perhaps those "things" that are necessary for your registration process, for instance

Comment: Because "Googlesaap_welcome" page traffic I don't want in my home page report suite.... and I know I can filter out with single click but i need some permanent solution to changing the code on my web page...

Comment: can you provide more details about the actual implementation?  Is the registration process in a different report suite? If so, you can change `s_account` to not point to your home page report suite for that page.  Usually you would do this with `dynamicAccountList`,`dynamicAccountSelection`, and possibly `dynamicAccountMatch`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely stop that page from being tracked, ie no beacon will be sent to Adobe, you can set "s.abort = true". Create a function after you set your s_account variable that matches the URL you want to filter and sets s.abort = true. Keep in mind, this will really mess up your referring data as the next page view will see an internal referral as the first page view on the visit. If you are using multi-suite tagging, you will lose all beacons to all report suites.

If I were you, I would create a segment that excludes page views or visits on that page from the report suite and look at the data that way. Or, if you just don't want to see the traffic that is bouncing, create your segment excluding and single page visits that entered on that page.

Aborting the pixel is a drastic step and should be very well thought out before employing that tactic.

Answer (score 0):

Use VISTA rules to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: Would work, but I consider this too heavy and costly for filtering out data from a page or few.